# Why target of click event is incorrect in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript

As you can observe in the enclosed picture(https://i.ibb.co/yQSTK0H/test-section.jpg), I have divided specified area into 3 sections. now the problem is that when i toggle to mobile device in chrome developer tools and I'm trying to click in the blue area event fires as if I have clicked in red section.
Why is this happening?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNxZKe

```js
$(".time-filter").click(function (e) {
  alert(e.target.className)
});
```

```css
.time-filter {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
}

.time-filter-content {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100px;
}

.red {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(59deg);
  background-color:red
}

.blue {
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: rotate(28deg);
  background-color:blue
}

.black {
  border-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-filter">
  <div class="time-filter-content">
    <div class="section red">
    </div>
    <div class="section blue">
    </div>
    <div class="section black">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue in current Chrome/Windows. It works as expected in e.g. Pixel 2 view.

Comment: Can't seem to replicate this issue... (MacOS Mojave, Chrome 75.0.3770.15)

Comment: Seem to work fine for me with Google Chrome.

Comment: Actually I can reproduce it now, if you click in the blue section towards the center of the circle.

Comment: Hmm good point me too.

Comment: Looking at this... seems it might be an issue with z-index and overlapping elements. https://monosnap.com/file/cxKnBLHVbptlCrmNJrw5Qrv5F0qjcm

Comment: According to the element inspector, the elements do **not** overlap.

Comment: Testing this on my mobile, if you zoom in it works just fine so maybe this is down to the touch selection radius used. Visit the codepen on your mobile and zoom in, you will see it will alert the correct color.

Comment: @NewToJS It does not work in chrome developer tools